# Need help extracting variables from a While Loop in VB.Net

Tags: sql, vb.net, variables, while-loop

I'm a novice with my coding so forgive me if my question seems basic but I'm having some trouble extracting my variables from this While Loop in order to then use the results of my SQL query for validation.

This script below is the event handling for a login button on an .aspx form processing an email and login field that will be listed in a correlating MSSQL database:

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
Protected Sub submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
    Dim Column1 As String
    Dim Column2 As String
    Dim SQL = "SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE Email='" & email.Text & "' AND Password='" & password.Text & "'"
    Dim oSqlDataReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Nothing
    Using oSqlConnection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("SERVER=[Server Name];UID=[User];PWD=[Pass];DATABASE=[Database Name]")
        oSqlConnection.Open()
        Using oSqlCommand As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, oSqlConnection)
            oSqlDataReader = oSqlCommand.ExecuteReader
            While oSqlDataReader.Read
                Column1 = oSqlDataReader(name:="Email")
                Column2 = oSqlDataReader(name:="Password")
            End While
        End Using
        oSqlConnection.Close()
    End Using        
    If "Column 1 etc."
    End if
End Sub
End Class
```

As far as I can tell my code is working with no errors but every time I try and create an If statement my Variable `Column 1 and Column 2` are undeclared making them useless.

If anyone could help with the correct layout for my code or missing areas and an explanation as to where I've gone wrong that'd be great.

Comment: Doing the `If` part after the loop has finished means that `Column1` and `Column2` will contain the last read values. Is that what you want?

Comment: The last valu returned should be fine yes. The SQL query should only return one value i.e. a valid email address and password, if a value is returned then I was deeming the email and password as being acceptable and proceeding.

As for security, I'm still a novice and understand it's not the most secure system, I'll definitely be looking up 'sql-parameters' now though for future use or in this project if I can get it working haha

Comment: Moving my If Statement stopped Visual Studio from putting up an error upon entering Debug Mode having Column 1 and Column as undeclared; thank you @David. 

They are still returning "Nothing" though but I suspect this is down to my server connection as I'm running SSMS 2014 with VS 2013; I'll try and get hold of an earlier SSMS. 

Thankyou for your help though everybody :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the `If` block inside the loop, do you get closer to the behaviour that you're expecting?

```
Protected Sub submit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles submit.Click
    Dim Column1 As String
    Dim Column2 As String
    Dim SQL = "SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE Email='" & email.Text & "' AND Password='" & password.Text & "'"

    Dim oSqlDataReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Nothing

    Using oSqlConnection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("SERVER=[Server Name];UID=[User];PWD=[Pass];DATABASE=[Database Name]")
        oSqlConnection.Open()

        Using oSqlCommand As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQL, oSqlConnection)
            oSqlDataReader = oSqlCommand.ExecuteReader

            While oSqlDataReader.Read
                Column1 = oSqlDataReader(name:="Email")
                Column2 = oSqlDataReader(name:="Password")

                If "Column 1 etc....."
                End if
            End While
        End Using

        oSqlConnection.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your query is returning no rows or that the values returned are dbNull or nothing. I would check the data getting returned and error if appropriate.

Try running the query against the database directly. Are you getting a row back?

To avoid the error, you can declare the string as String.empty

```
Dim Column1 As String = String.empty
```

Or, when using it in the if statement check for nothing:

```
If Column1 Is Not Nothing AndAlso ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use string concatenation to build your sql query. Instead use sql-parameters to prevent sql injection and other issues.

I must admit that i don't know this syntax: `oSqlDataReader(name:="Email")`. Use following:

```
Dim email As String
Dim password As String
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Logins WHERE Email=@Email AND Password=@Password"

Using oSqlConnection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("SERVER=[Server Name];UID=[User];PWD=[Pass];DATABASE=[Database Name]")
    Using oSqlCommand As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, oSqlConnection)
        oSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = email.Text
        oSqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password.Text
        oSqlConnection.Open()
        Using oSqlDataReader = oSqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
            If oSqlDataReader.Read() Then
                Dim emailColIndex = oSqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("Email")
                Dim pwdColIndex = oSqlDataReader.GetOrdinal("Password")
                email = oSqlDataReader.GetString(emailColIndex)
                password = oSqlDataReader.GetString(pwdColIndex)
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Using ' oSqlConnection.Close() not needed with using '

If email IsNot Nothing AndAlso password IsNot Nothing Then

End If
```

But instead of initializing two string variables you should implement a `Login` class that you can initialize and return from the method. You don't want to know the email and the password since you already have them.

Since this is ASP.NET i suggest to look at the available [membership provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) which are powerful and have a learning curve, but it's definitely worth the time.